# CSS selector that selects preceding sibling element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following table:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr:not(.header) td:not(.empty) {
    background: #eee;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
td.empty {
    width: 25px;
    background: white;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
tbody tr.header + tr td:not(.empty){ border-top: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
            <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header">
            <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="header">
            <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The markup is generated by the Kendo framework. I am using Kendo Grids with the groupable feature enabled (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/api). I cannot edit the markup provided.

And I am trying to put the same red border on the bottom of the gray areas, but I'm not sure I'm going to be able to in pure CSS. I was messing around with the adjacent/general sibling selectors, but no luck.

Here's what the table should look like:

[image]

Is there any way (in pure CSS) to give a red border to the bottom of the gray areas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @dcc - the empty class td is never the last child so that wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't agree with down voting and not explaining, but it is in fact not good markup.  You're trying to group together elements that don't logically group.  Random headers thrown in here and there, not using nesting or grouping, and not using `th` or similar.  It's no wonder it's hard to find a solution.  I suggest taking all your header/cell group pairs and wrapping them in `tbody`s.  It's valid markup to do so and with that you could using `tr + tr` syntax or `:last-child`.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean its bad markup. That is quite literally the format of the markup provided from Telerik's Kendo. Its what I have to work with.

Comment: It may be a third party vendor, but it's still bad markup.  The fact that it's a struggle to do this otherwise simple task is evidence of it being less than ideal.  I am, however, very curious why they did it this way, now.  Maybe it has to do with pagination or some other factor that's not quite obvious?

Comment: Yes, maybe this is perceived as bad mark up because I left out some context. The headers are grouping in a tabular grid. You can group data by columns. When I get back to a computer, I'll provide a demo page.

Comment: Here's the demo I was talking about: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/api
For the application, this mark up makes sense and is actually quite semantic, rather than nesting data for the sake of style.

Comment: That being said, I understand where you are coming from @JosephMarikle. I appreciate your constructive comments very much. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    tr:not(.header) td:not(.empty) {
        background: #eee;
        width: 100px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    td.empty {
        width: 25px;
        background: white;
        border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
    tbody tr.header + tr td:not(.empty){ border-top: 1px solid red; }
table { position:relative; }
table:after { content:'\A';position:absolute;bottom:0;width:89%;left:27px;border-bottom:1px solid red; }
tr.header:before { content:'\A';height:1px;left:27px;position:absolute;width:89%;border-top:1px solid red; }
tr.header:first-of-type:before { border-top:none; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3">HEADER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Rather than setting `width: 89%`, I'd suggest setting `right: 0` instead. In doing so, it should work for varying widths (assuming that there will always be a 27px of empty space on the side.)

Comment: Tried that, but the table is wider than the grey area.

Comment: If you remove `width: 89%` and relatively position the parent element (`.empty { position: relative; }`) it will work along side `right: 0`.

Comment: This is very close. Though it does move the header text to the right a good amount.